# check user_input with if token in a loop

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that checks my input to see whether I have entered the character '?'.

This is what I got so far:

```
def check_word():
   word = []
   check = 0
   user_input = input('Please enter a word that does not contain ?: ')

   for token in user_input.split():
      if token == '?':
        print('Error')
check_word()
```

My input: hello?
It is supposed to show 'Error'. But it doesn't show anything. Could you please tell me what wrong it is in my code.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `in` operator to do this

```
def check_word(s):
    if '?' in s:
        print('Error')
```

For example

```
>>> check_word('foobar')
>>> check_word('foo?')
Error
```

Comment: Oops my mistake. I could have sworn I saw that they wanted to check for `'?'` or whitespace, but now that I re-read it I guess my mind made that up!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you split the string of the `user_input`.

```
user_input.split():
```

The example doesn't contain whitespaces so the condition isn't met. If you want for example to check a sentence with spaces, you should split it like this: `user_input.split(' ')` to split it on the spaces.

But for this example you have two choices:

1) You can just iterate over the input itself because you want to check every char in the string for whether it's a `?`.

That is, change `user_input.split():` into simply `user_input` without splitting. This option is good if you might ever want to add some sort of action for each char.

2) It's very easy just to use `in`, like this:

```
if '?' in s:
    print('There is a question mark in the string')
```

This is a very simple solution that you can expand and check for other chars in the string as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `user_input.split()` splits the `user_input` by whitespace. Since `hello?` does not contain any whitespaces, `token` is equal to your input and the loop is executed once.

You should iterate over `user_input` instead, or simply check `if '?' in user_input`.